# Swap partition and swap file at the same time?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, partition, swap

I've added the swap file while having the swap partition:

```
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file        4G   6M   -1
/dev/dm-0 partition 1,9G   0B   -2
```

The size of RAM is 4GB. I'm on Linux Mint 18.3 MATE (based on Ubuntu 16.04)

Could anything possibly go wrong?

Is it worth to reinstall everything, increase swap partition and do not use swap file at all?

Comment: No, why would that be a problem? You seem impatient, less then 5 minutes between the question and the follow up.

Comment: Why the down-votes (please give feedback). This may seem like a dumb question (to those that know), but to those that don't know it may not be dumb.

Comment: Please tell why you think that this can not be done.

Comment: I don't know why the down-votes. Apparently, somebody thinks that every person on this planet knows how Linux works and I'm a dumb guy. Didn't see a similar question on StackExchange, so I decided to ask straight.

Comment: I've actually added swap file while having swap partition for now. Everything looks good just like I wanted. But I guess it's better to reinstall everything, increase swap partition and do not use swap file at all. Am I wrong?

Comment: And thank you for asking. I don't see anything wrong with this question other than a lack of detail. Perhaps you could clarify what operating system(s) you are using (yes, I know you added a tag, but please mention it in the question, we don't use tags that way) and maybe some information about how you have set up your swap partition and file. Still, I admit I don't understand how this question received 4 downvotes. Apparently, some users forget we were all new to this once and had to learn. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use both at same time, file  is just slower.
so NO there is no risk doing that but performances if file writing is on while other activities on disks are provided.

But you should use file as low priority & swap disk partition as first priority  to limit performance loose when swap is used.

Comment: Thank for the answer. Right now, I don't see the difference but, we'll see...

Comment: Could you expand on this a little? As it stands, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I complete the answer if it's not clear enough ...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

set swap patition -2 and swapfile -3